# Is my C ping script secure?

Tags: c, cgi

I just wrote a ping script in C for CGI.

It is working as intended but I am pretty sure that it is not secure because I take the user input for granted.
I do not know if there is a way to stitch a command together so that it is still recognised?

Does somebody know how to exploit my script and how I should fix it?

**ping script source**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=us-ascii\n\n");

  FILE* in = NULL;

  char buffer[100][100] = {};
  char server[100] = {};
  char concat_str[100] = {};

  char* ping = "ping ";
  char* option = " -c 4";

  int print_counter = 0;
  int read_counter = 0;

  char* query;
  query = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
  if(query == NULL)
    printf("ERROR\n");
  else
    sscanf(query,"server=%s", server);

  strcat(concat_str, ping);
  strcat(concat_str, server);
  strcat(concat_str, option);

  in = popen(concat_str, "r");
  if(in == NULL)
  {
    printf("ERROR\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  while(fgets(buffer[read_counter], 99, in) != NULL)
  {
    read_counter++;
  }

  pclose(in);

  if(read_counter != 9)
  {
    printf("ERROR\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  while(print_counter < (read_counter + 1))
  {
    printf("%s", buffer[print_counter]);
    print_counter++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**html source**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/ping.cgi">
<div><label>Server<input name="server" size="40"></label></div>
<div><input type="submit" value="start test"></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

On a related note, is there an easy way to post the source code directly here without manually intending it 4 spaces?

Comment: i realize there is a problem with strcat because i do not check how large the server length is and it might become too big :)

Comment: Paste your code into your post, highlight it, and click the **`{ }`** button.

Comment: Susan, thanks for the post. However, I think this should be moved to code review.

Comment: Thanks, that makes things easier :)

Comment: s.bandara: Sorry i did not know that there is a more appropriate category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not secure. The `popen()` function passes its argument to a subshell, so shell metacharacters like `;` could be passed in through the query string to execute an arbitrary command.

Comment: Thanks, would it be enough to write a sanitize function to just allow A-Z a-z and dots?

Comment: That'd correct the issue I mentioned, but I can't guarantee that other security-critical bugs don't still exist. I'd strongly advise writing this in a language other than C.

Comment: One could also pass `&& do_something`. Also should specify the full path to ping. Otherwise, if there's a `ping` in the same directory, it will try to execute that. And use whitelisting rather than blacklisting - things get much simpler and safer.

Comment: Yeah, same principle. There are a bunch of metacharacters which can be used here -- `;` is just the simplest one.

Comment: I tried to stitch the command like this together "ping ;ping google.com > test -c 1; -c 4" while i am able to print the output(to a file) if i launch it directly in the shell i am unable to do so via the script. Does anybody have a concrete example how to make it do something unexpected?

Answer (score 4):

1. All strings literals should be const. E.g.: `const char *v = "value"`, or `const char v[] = "value"`.
2. Your `sscanf` may cause a stack overflow. Tell it to read at most N characters and it should be safe. E.g.: `sscanf(query,"server=%99s", server);`.
3. Calling `strcat` without having total control over the buffers is also likely to cause a stack overflow. Use `strncat` instead. E.g.: `strncat(concat_str, option, sizeof(concat_str)-strlen(concat_str)-1)`.
4. Your `while(fgets(buffer[read_counter], 99, in) != NULL)` may also loop indefinitely and access an out-of-bound position in your `buffer` array. You should also check whether `read_counter` is within the valid range, `0..99`.

Comment: Thanks, i quickly stitched it together and didn't think much of it. But i am more interested in the possible injections directly to the shell.

Comment: You're welcome. No problem, @duskwuff correctly figured it out for you. Glad we helped.